# Make sense of the error message "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'"

Tags: typescript

Here is my isolated code:

```js
type IDontCare = any;

let aFunction: (params: unknown) => IDontCare;
aFunction = (hello: string) => 0;
```

And I got the error message `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'`. I wonder, isn't it I'm trying to **assign 'string' to 'unknown'** instead? I can't wrap my head around this error message, and would love to hear some explanation. Thanks.

| Code | Error message |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: The `aFunction` should be allowed to be passed anywhere where `(p: unknown) => ...` is allowed to be passed. But your function is stricter than that. You should be able to call `aFunction(42);`, but your implementation does not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `(params: A) => number` is assignable to `(params: B) => number`,
you expect `(params: A) => number` behaves the same as `(params: B) => number`,

i.e. `(params: A) => number` can take a params of type `B` and return a `number`.

That means you are trying to check if a `B` can be passed into `(params: A) => number`. The result is you are trying to assign `B` to `A`. If `B` is not assignable to `A`, then `(params: A) => number` is not assignable to `(params: B) => number`.

In other words, you need `B` to be assignable to `A` in order for `(params: A) => number` to be assignable to `(params: B) => number`

Answer (score 0):

Type of `aFunction` says, that it can receive argument of any type. So, you should assign to `aFunction` function that can do the same or even more.

`(hello: string) => 0` cannot take any argument (actually, it takes only `string`), so it is not assignable to `aFunction`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "can receive argument of any type", as if I change from `unknown` to `any` (literally "argument of any type"), there will be no errors.