# How is type compatibility checked between call signatures?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following snippet:

```
type Add = (a: number | string, b: number | string) => number | string;

function hof(cb: Add) {}

const addNum = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
const addStr = (a: string, b: string): string => a + b;

// @ts-expect-error
hof(addNum);
// @ts-expect-error
hof(addStr);
```

Why can't we pass `addNum` and `addStr` functions to `hof`, IMO their call signatures should be compatible with what `hof` expects, but it actually isn't.

And if their types are incompatible, then why doesn't the overload signatures in the following snippet complain?

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number;
function add(a: string, b: string): string;
function add(a: number | string, b: number | string): number | string {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You can refer to [one of my answer in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430179/make-sense-of-the-error-message-type-unknown-is-not-assignable-to-type-strin/70430220#70430220) for how function type checking works.

Answer (score 6):

You are assuming covariant types, but function arguments are contravariant. (see [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/) for some depth on this.)

---

Change your example a bit to this, and you start to see the problem:

```
type Add = (a: number | string, b: number | string) => number | string;

function hof(cb: Add) {
  return cb
}

const addNum = (a: number, b: number): number => Math.round(a) + Math.round(b);
const addStr = (a: string, b: string): string => `${a.toLowerCase()}${b.toLowerCase}`;

hof(addNum)('a', 'b'); // should error because addNum can't take strings
hof(addStr)(123, 456); // should error because addStr can't take numbers
```

Here `hof` returns the callback function you pass it. So if you pass it `addNum` then strings would crash. And if you pass it `addStr` then numbers would crash.

So for a function to be assignable to a function type it must take the *superset* of all argument types and *not a subset.*

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKAKAhgLigOwK4C2ARhAE5QA+UAzsKQJY4DmANFEdvsWZTXY0wCUyAHy5CJclVoNmAbgCwAKGUAzPDgDGwegHscUABa7VqTR1gJhAb2VQopCMDykD55QF9lyzftpR0BAA5QmQ0LHFuUjYLLklBTgkeJDEAWXRgQwA6Ul0NOAxhAGoodMycvJwCokFFJV8cf0C4AGU6MIxsGQEYrv5mBL5ZJlEoAAMAEmt0LOBdABldAHcyAGF0aghUQQ8polmF5bWNiA8xuuVjU2aQgkFUAHJ0B7YHogfaqAB6L5pjPAANogyLlyCRNOg8JsAsFQhCcA9gFBgOgANbQbrMaiXEwYBBtUj3ACMACYAMxsAAsAFYAGyfH5-PJAqAg3RgiAQqHQZoEqDwxHItHQOJkahAA)

---

However, if you make `hof` generic then you can create a function type from the arguments. For example:

```
type Add<T extends number | string> = (a: T, b: T) => T;

function hof<T extends number | string>(cb: Add<T>): Add<T> {
  return cb
}

const addNum = (a: number, b: number): number => Math.round(a) + Math.round(b);
const addStr = (a: string, b: string): string => `${a.toLowerCase()}${b.toLowerCase}`;

hof(addNum)(123, 456); // fine
hof(addStr)('a', 'B'); // fine

hof(addNum)('a', 'b'); // should error because addNum can't take strings
hof(addStr)(123, 456); // should error because addStr can't take numbers
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAPAFShAHsCA7OBnKbAVwFsAjCAJygB8o9hKBLbAcwD4oBeKACgEMAXFGQAaKGWHIAlN07IA3AFgAUKoBmRbAGNgTAPbYoAC33qUaTDnyFSFanQbM27XtsmwEKdtOHwkyJwA3qpQUJQQwESURu6qAL6qqtqGDFD8CABypNx8QrbkVOIexIWUvgX2clAAsvzAxgB0lPpacAKyANS19U0tbbxk0soqKdhpGXAAyoy5AsJOLKzFC4xLFYts1QAGACRB-I3A+gAy+gDuVADC-HgQvNLx+2RHpxfXtxDx2yOqpuoCLKkaS8ACMACYAMziAAsAFYAGzDKAAehRUHULAgfzMgOmjBBAHJ+ITxISAEKE5FojFYpIqf547IkIkkslkKkKVHovCmIgAGzgaEoLWoFG0-CId3SQJIUAl2EJwCgwH4AGtoJtWHgcQDJjNymCobDEdSeXzBcLRRIIBKpdB9bMFUqVeroKV7DqVEA)

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's happening here, we to need understand the ways in which the `hof` function is allowed to use the `cb` that is passed to it.

### What arguments can be passed?

Let's consider a simpler example, consisting of only a single argument.

```
function hof(cb: (a: number | string) => number | string) {}
```

So, `hof` is stating that it expects a callback function, `cb`, that takes in a single argument that can be a number or a string, and it returns a string or a number.

Now, think of the restrictions that TS would apply on `hof` in terms of what it can pass to `cb`. So, `hof` is allowed to call `cb` with either a `number` or a `string` and this is *okay* because `hof` has stated that the `cb` that it receives should be able to handle both a number and a string.

But, if you pass the following `double` function to `hof`, TS would complain:

```
function double(a: number): number {
  return 2 * a
}
```

And this makes sense because `hof` can call this `double` function with a `string` which might break the `double` function because it's meant to accept only numbers.

Also notice the place where the error is thrown, it's thrown right where `hof` is invoked with `double`, indicating that something is wrong with how `hof` is being called and *not* with how it's implemented.

```
function hof(cb: (a: number | string) => number | string) {}

function double(a: number): number {
  return 2 * a
}

// @ts-expect-error
hof(double)
```

**So, the callbacks passed to `hof` should be able to handle a superset of arguments that `hof` is allowed to pass to the callback.**

[image]

### How can the return type be used?

Now let's see the ways in which `hof` can use the value returned by `cb`.

Because `cb` can return either a `number` or a `string`, it's `hof`'s responsibility to use the return value wisely, meaning that `hof` should *not* assume that the returned value is *always* a number or a string, `hof` needs to put appropriate type guards before making any such assumptions.

```
function hof(cb: (a: number | string) => number | string) {
  // @ts-expect-error
  const fixed = cb(100).toFixed() // wrong assumption that the returned value is always a number
}

function hof(cb: (a: number | string) => number | string) {
  const ret = cb(100)
  if (typeof ret === "number") { // appropriate check to make sure that it's a number
    const fixed = ret.toFixed();
  }
}
```

And again notice the place where the error is thrown, it's thrown inside the function body indicating that there's a problem with the implementation of the function.

The callback passed to `hof` can also *just* return a `number` and TS would be absolutely fine with that.

```
function hof(cb: (a: number | string) => number | string) {}

function double(a: number | string): number {
  return 2 * Number(a)
}

hof(double)
```

**So, the callbacks passed to `hof` should *only* return a subset of values that `hof` expects the callback to return.**

[image]

### Overload Signatures

The behavior with overload signatures is different, the purpose of overloading is to restrict the behavior of a function.

**So, arguments and return values of overload signatures should always be a subset of the arguments and return values of the implementation signature.**

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** `hof` needs the callback to cover more cases than either of these functions can handle alone.

---

You got it the wrong way around in this case.

`hof` specifies that its callback will be called with two arguments, either of which may be a string or a number. That means that a function only capable of handling two number arguments is not sufficient (since it might also get passed a string).

So, something the other way around would work:

```
function hof(cb: (a: number, b: number) => number) {}

function add(a: number | string, b: number | string): number | string {
  return 1;
}

hof(add);
```

Because in this case add is guaranteed to be able to handle two numbers passed to it (at least based on its signature).

---

So why does the overload signature work then? Because the context is an entirely different one. As overloads of the function, they are perfectly correct as they are more specific signatures of the more general one. But that is the wrong direction for function arguments where you need to pass a function with parameters as specific as required by the function **or less specific**. You passed a function with *more* specific parameters.